# why tempData always null when add many item in tempData?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, tempdata

why TempData always null when add many item in TempData ?

my code in controller :

```
TempData[Partial1.TempDataKey] = "bla bla";
TempData[Partial2.TempDataKey] = "bla bla 2";
```

my code in layout :

```
@{Html.RenderPartial(MVC.Administrator.Shared.Views._Partial1);}
@{Html.RenderPartial(MVC.Administrator.Shared.Views._Partial2);}
```

my code in _Partial1:

```
<span>@(TempData.ContainsKey(Partial1.TempDataKey))</span>
```

my code in _Partial2:

```
<span>@(TempData.ContainsKey(Partial2.TempDataKey))</span>
```

result always is:

```
<span>False</span>
<span>False</span>
```

when i remove on of them in controller :

```
TempData[Partial1.TempDataKey] = "bla bla";
//TempData[Partial2.TempDataKey] = "bla bla 2";
```

then result is :

```
  <span>True</span>
```

Comment: Use ViewBag or ViewData inplace of your tempdata. The reason is Tempdata is only useful for controller to controller data passing. Also once you read it its life is over.

Comment: viewbag and viewdata : If redirection occurs then it’s value becomes null.

Answer (score 3):

The variables in TempData are automatically marked for deletion after they have been accessed. You can retain them by explicitly calling Keep method

> You can use a TempDataDictionary object to pass data in the same way
> that you use a ViewDataDictionary object. However, **the data in a
> TempDataDictionary object persists only from one request to the next,
> unless you mark one or more keys for retention by using the Keep
> method**. If a key is marked for retention, the key is retained for the
> next request.
>
> A typical use for a TempDataDictionary object is to pass
> data from an action method when it redirects to another action method.
> For example, an action method might store information about an error
> in the controller's TempData property (which returns a
> TempDataDictionary object) before it calls the RedirectToAction
> method. The next action method can then handle the error and render a
> view that displays an error message.

Source: [TempDataDictionary Class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.tempdatadictionary(v=vs.118).aspx)

For I was curious about its lifecycle so I went through the source code and blogged about it if interested in further reading: [Inner-workings of TempData in ASP.NET MVC 5](http://volkanpaksoy.com/archive/2015/09/14/innerworkings-of-tempdata-in-aspnet-mvc5/)

You can also call Peek method to retrieve values and still retaining them.